# Understanding when to call zero_grad() in pytorch, when training with multiple losses

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am going through an open-source implementation of a domain-adversarial model (GAN-like). The implementation uses pytorch and I am not sure they use `zero_grad()` correctly. They call `zero_grad()` for the encoder optimizer (aka the generator) before updating the discriminator loss. However `zero_grad()` is hardly documented, and I couldn't find information about it.

Here is a psuedo code comparing a standard GAN training (option 1), with their implementation (option 2). I think the second option is wrong, because it may accumulate the D_loss gradients with the E_opt. Can someone tell if these two pieces of code are equivalent?

Option 1 (a standard GAN implementation):

```
X, y = get_D_batch()
D_opt.zero_grad()
pred = model(X)
D_loss = loss(pred, y)
D_opt.step()

X, y = get_E_batch()
E_opt.zero_grad()
pred = model(X)
E_loss = loss(pred, y)
E_opt.step()
```

Option 2 (calling `zero_grad()` for both optimizers at the beginning):

```
E_opt.zero_grad()
D_opt.zero_grad()

X, y = get_D_batch()
pred = model(X)
D_loss = loss(pred, y)
D_opt.step()

X, y = get_E_batch()
pred = model(X)
E_loss = loss(pred, y)
E_opt.step()
```

Comment: For one thing you’ve got a lowercase x that you never refer to anywhere else.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy They might be equivalent (at least in how they work), it depends on what `get_D_batch()` actually does, see below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on `params` argument of [`torch.optim.Optimizer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer) subclasses (e.g. [`torch.optim.SGD`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.SGD)) and exact structure of the model.

Assuming `E_opt` and `D_opt` have different set of parameters (`model.encoder` and `model.decoder` do not share weights), something like this:

```
E_opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.encoder.parameters())
D_opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.decoder.parameters())
```

both options **MIGHT** indeed be equivalent (see commentary for your source code, additionally I have added `backward()` which is really important here and also changed `model` to `discriminator` and `generator` appropriately as I assume that's the case):

```
# Starting with zero gradient
E_opt.zero_grad()
D_opt.zero_grad()

# See comment below for possible cases
X, y = get_D_batch()
pred = discriminator(x)
D_loss = loss(pred, y)
# This will accumulate gradients in discriminator only
# OR in discriminator and generator, depends on other parts of code
# See below for commentary
D_loss.backward()
# Correct weights of discriminator
D_opt.step()

# This only relies on random noise input so discriminator
# Is not part of this equation
X, y = get_E_batch()
pred = generator(x)
E_loss = loss(pred, y)
E_loss.backward()
# So only parameters of generator are updated always
E_opt.step()
```

Now it's all about `get_D_Batch` feeding data to discriminator.

### Case 1 - real samples

This is not a problem as it does not involve generator, you pass real samples and only `discriminator` takes part in this operation.

### Case 2 - generated samples

#### Naive case

Here indeed gradient accumulation may occur. It would occur if `get_D_batch` would simply call `X = generator(noise)` and passed this data to `discriminator`.
In such case both `discriminator` and `generator` have their gradients accumulated during `backward()` as both are used.

#### Correct case

We should take `generator` out of the equation. Taken from [PyTorch DCGan example](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) there is a little line like this:

```
# Generate fake image batch with G
fake = generator(noise)
label.fill_(fake_label)
# DETACH HERE
output = discriminator(fake.detach()).view(-1)
```

What `detach` does is it "stops" the gradient by `detach`ing it from the computational graph. So gradients will not be backpropagated along this variable. This effectively does not impact gradients of `generator` so it has no more gradients so no accumulation happens.

Another way (IMO better) would be to use `with.torch.no_grad():` block like this:

```
# Generate fake image batch with G
with torch.no_grad():
    fake = generator(noise)
label.fill_(fake_label)
# NO DETACH NEEDED
output = discriminator(fake).view(-1)
```

This way `generator` operations will not build part of the graph so we get better performance (it would in the first case but would be detached afterwards).

### Finally

Yeah, all in all first option is better for standard GANs as one doesn't have to think about such stuff (people implementing it should, but readers should not). Though there are also other approaches like single optimizer for both `generator` and `discriminator` (one cannot `zero_grad()` only for subset of parameters (e.g. `encoder`) in this case), weight sharing and others which further clutter the picture.

`with torch.no_grad()` should alleviate the problem in all/most cases as far as I can tell and imagine ATM.

Comment: After `E_loss = loss(pred, y)` shouldn't be also E_loss.backward()?  @Szymon Maszke